# Stop website publishing in DEBUG mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, debugging, https, config

I know that this hasn't always been the case, so I have changed something at some point.

Basically, I have code

```
#if !DEBUG
    [RequireHttps(Order = 1)]       
#endif
```

So it forces https in live mode. It used to work, but now it isn't. ( It is always in debug mode now)

My Web.config is set to live mode:

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
```

Is there anywhere else I should change it?

Edit: I cant change this to Release, its not saving.
[image]

Comment: this is a bad idea - why don't you use iis express to test ssl?

Comment: How do you set IIS express to test SSL? I thought it was http only.

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx

Comment: A lot of detail for what is really just clicking two options. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably changed your project's build configuration from `Release` to `Debug`. You can switch it back in your project's Build properties tab.